# Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare(), called in /dbtable.php on line 252 and defined in /public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1246

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Everyday I see this error in log file:

> PHP Warning:  Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare(), called in /home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/affiliate-link-cloaking/dbtable.php on line 252 and defined in /home/xxxxxx/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1246

In /dbtable.php on line 252 I have this code:

```
$result = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("DELETE FROM ". $this->track_table_name . " WHERE YEAR(visittime)=". date('Y',$sdate) . " AND MONTH(visittime)=" . date('m',$sdate) ));
```

And in /wp-db.php on line 1246 I have this code:

```
public function prepare( $query, $args ) {
```

Please, keep in mind that I'm very inexperienced in PHP/SQL and I'll not understand general kind of tips. Please tell me, what to copy and paste where))

Thanks

Comment: Instead of `I'll not understand general kind of tips` and `Please tell me, what to copy and paste where` you should read your code and understand what it is doing, and how the functions are meant to be used. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/

Comment: Sorry, but for me it's like the Chinese and it is not a crime. )

Comment: This site is designed to help you learn, not necessarily a place to get things fixed for free. Everyone starts as a beginner. If it's helpful, here are the guidelines on the types of questions/answers supported by the site: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

That is not the correct way to use `$wpdb->prepare`, the first value should be the SQL with replacement tokens (`%s`=string, `%d`=digit, etc), followed by the values to replace them with.

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM {$this->track_table_name} WHERE YEAR(visittime) = %d AND MONTH(visittime) = %d";
$query = $wpdb->prepare($sql, date('Y', $sdate), date('m', $sdate))
$wpdb->query($query);
```

See examples here: 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/

Comment: Does it mean, I must change this code `$result = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("DELETE FROM ". $this->track_table_name . " WHERE YEAR(visittime)=". date('Y',$sdate) . " AND MONTH(visittime)=" . date('m',$sdate) ));` with yours?)

Comment: It would probably work but I obviously haven't tested it. Use it as an example of how to properly use `$wpdb->prepare()`.